# How to evaluate this multiple integral?

Tags: integration

How do I show that $\int_{0<t_1<t_2<…<t_n<t} dt_1…dt_n$ = $\frac{t^n}{n!}$.

For the case of n=2, this was what I got, which is think is wrong but isn’t sure why: $$\int_{0<t_1<t_2<t}dt_1dt_2=\int(\int \mathbb{1}_{0<t_1<t_2<t} \;dt_1)dt_2=\int \mathbb{1}_{0<t_2<t}\;dt_2=\frac{t}{2}$$

Comment: Could you do the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$?

Comment: @dante: What have you tried so far? The several first cases can you give some idea.

Comment: Induction on $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For $n=2$, we can do the following:
Let
$$
I=\int_{0<t_1<t_2<t} d t_1 dt_2
$$

Then
$$
2I = \int_{0<t_1<t_2<t} d t_1 dt_2+\int_{0<t_2<t_1<t} d t_1 dt_2 = \int_{0<t_1,t_2<t} d t_1 dt_2=t^2
$$
$$
I = \frac{t^2}{2}
$$

How could you treat the case of general $n$ similarly?